# sql select returning multiple results per field

Tags: sql, filemaker

I would appreciate assistance with the following:

I have two tables Data and Results.
Data has the columns `date`, `stock_price`, `strike_price`
Results has the column `earnings_date`

Data has about 1m rows and for each date there are many `strike_price` entries but one `stock_price`. e.g.

- date    stock_price  strike_price

  - 4/1/2013   100        75
  - 4/1/2013   100        85
  - 4/1/2013   100        95
  - 4/2/2013   102        75
  - 4/2/2013   102        85
  - 4/2/2013   102        95
  - 4/3/2013   105        75
  - 4/3/2013   105        85
  - 4/3/2013   105      85

What I am trying to do is, when in the Results table, find the `stock_price` for each earnings date.

So for example Results:

- earnings_date stock_price
- 4/1/2013        100
- 4/2/2013        102
- 4/3/2013        105

I have tried the following:

```
select distinct Data.stock_price from Data join Results on Data.date = Results.earnings_date
```

but I get all the stock prices in each row:

- earnings_date stock_price
- 4/1/2013        100102105
- 4/2/2013        100102105
- 4/2/2013        100102105

Any assistance appreciated.
(using Filemaker pro 12)

Comment: Do Data and Results tables have same number of rows? I mean for all date in Data table, are there corresponding earning_date in Results table?

Comment: `select Results.earnings_date, Data.stock_price from Data join Results on Data.date = Results.earnings_date group by Results.earnings_date,Data.stock_price`

Comment: Zane: no data has close to 1m rows, results has a couple of hundred. thanks

Comment: @DinupKandel: thanks but I still get multiple results in one field although it picked up a few results my original statement had missed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select r.earnings_date, d.stock_price from Data d, Results r
where d.date = r.earnings_date 
group by r.earnings_date,d.stock_price;
```

I think, it should work, for example, I'd checked it with `Data` table with 5 rows & `Results` table with 3 rows. If problem persists, add comment below.

Comment: Thanks but I still get all the results in each row instead of one result in each row. For example, 4/1/2013 should have 100, but it has 4/1/2013 100102105

Comment: Do you have unique stock_price for a particular date 4/1/2013 or not?

Comment: yes for each date there is only 1 stock price (but a whole host of other data which means you get approx. 200 records for each date, but all with 1 stock price

Comment: they all come out exactly the same. till i get the code right, I'm working on a subset of the big data table anyway and can eyeball that this is the case as well

Comment: would a nested select work? if so how would that be structured?

Comment: I've uploaded here:https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwa2aFqJYTteRlFYRnFxSjRwYzA/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwa2aFqJYTtedDk4emwwM2l2UTg/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwa2aFqJYTteTmE1WV9yZVJsYTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: filemaker doesn't seem to be able to do it. sorry

Comment: I need to download the Filemaker to open your files. As you say it's not working just for one date, what I think is there are three stock_price values 100 102 & 105 for the date 4/1/2013 in table Data. So try to check using Stock_price = 102 and date=4/1/2013 in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify the row separator in function call.